# How to declare an array variable and its size mid-routine in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran

I would like to create an array with a dimension based on the number of elements meeting a certain condition in another array. This would require that I initialize an array mid-routine, which Fortran won't let me do.

Is there a way around that?

**Example routine:**

```
subroutine example(some_array)

real some_array(50) ! passed array of known dimension

element_count = 0
do i=1,50
  if (some_array.gt.0) then
    element_count = element_count+1
  endif
enddo

real new_array(element_count) ! new array with length based on conditional statement

endsubroutine example
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question isn't about *initializing* an array, which involves setting its values.

However, there is a way to do what you want.  You even have a choice, depending on how general it's to be.

I'm assuming that the `element_count` means to have a `some_array(i)` in that loop.

You can make `new_array` `allocatable`:

```
subroutine example(some_array)
  real some_array(50)
  real, allocatable :: new_array(:)

  allocate(new_array(COUNT(some_array.gt.0)))
end subroutine
```

Or have it as an automatic object:

```
subroutine example(some_array)
  real some_array(50)
  real new_array(COUNT(some_array.gt.0))
end subroutine
```

This latter works only when your condition is "simple".  Further, automatic objects cannot be used in the scope of modules or main programs. The `allocatable` case is much more general, such as when you want to use the full loop rather than the `count` intrinsic, or want the variable not as a procedure local variable.

In both of these cases you meet the requirement of having all the declarations before executable statements.

Since Fortran 2008 the `block` construct allows automatic objects even after executable statements and in the main program:

```
program example

  implicit none

  real some_array(50)
  some_array = ...

  block
    real new_array(COUNT(some_array.gt.0))
  end block

end program example
```

Comment: What is the correct term then? The automatic object looks like the most straightforward to me for this example. Interesting about Fortran 2008. I'm new to Fortran, and the code I'm working on has a mixture of syntax from different verions, which leaves me confused at times.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
real, dimension(50) :: some_array
real, dimension(:), allocatable :: other_array
integer :: status
...
allocate(other_array(count(some_array>0)),stat=status)
```

at the end of this sequence of statements `other_array` will have the one element for each element of `some_array` greater than 0, there is no need to write a loop to count the non-zero elements of `some_array`.

Following @AlexanderVogt's advice, do check the status of the `allocate` statement.

Comment: this is definitely a much better approach than my loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `allocatable` arrays for this task:

```
subroutine example(some_array)

real             :: some_array(50)
real,allocatable :: new_array(:)
integer          :: i, element_count, status

element_count = 0
do i=lbound(some_array,1),ubound(some_array,1)
  if ( some_array(i) > 0 ) then
    element_count = element_count + 1
  endif
enddo

allocate( new_array(element_count), stat=status )
if ( status /= 0 ) stop 'cannot allocate memory'

! set values of new_array

end subroutine
```

Comment: Checking the status is great. I wonder if such a think exists in `C`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an `allocatable` array (see [this article for more on it](http://pages.swcp.com/~walt/fortran_store/Html/Info/books/t90_2.html)). This would change your routine to

```
subroutine example(input_array,output_array)

  real,intent(in) :: input_array(50) ! passed array of known dimension
  real, intent(out), allocatable :: output_array(:)
  integer :: element_count, i

  element_count = 0
  do i=1,50
    if (some_array.gt.0) element_count = element_count+1
  enddo

  allocate(output_array(element_count))

end subroutine
```

Note that the `intent`s may not be necessary, but are probably good practice. If you don't want to call a second array, it is possible to create a reallocate subroutine; though this would require the array to already be declared as `allocatable`.

Comment: Is there a reasoning behind why intent is good practice here? thanks!

Comment: @shootingstars: [see this link](http://nf.nci.org.au/training/FortranAdvanced/slides/slides.015.html) but note also [there are some caveats](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~szymansk/OOF90/bugs.html#2).