# Fortran tensor product of vectors

Tags: fortran, linear-algebra

I'm trying to calculate a [tensor/Kronecker product](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckerProduct.html) in Fortran for two vectors `x=[1,4]` and complex `y=[2+i,3+2i,3-i]`. The solution `z` should be an array `[2+i, 3+2i, 3-i, 8+4i, 12+8i, 12-4i]`. In my MWE,

```
program myfun

  implicit none
  real, dimension (:), allocatable :: x
  complex, dimension (:), allocatable :: y
  complex, dimension (:), allocatable :: z
  integer :: i, j  ! indexing
  integer :: k=1  ! indexing

  x = (/ 1,4 /)
  y = (/ 2,3,3 /) + (/ 1,2,-1 /) * cmplx(0,1)

  allocate(z(size(x)*size(y)))

  do i = 1,size(x)
    do j = 1,size(y)
      z(k) = x(i) * y(j)
      print *, x(i) * y(j)
      k = k+1
    end do
  end do

  print *, z
  print *, KronProd(x,y)

contains

  function KronProd(A,B) result(C)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    real, dimension (:,:), intent(in)  :: A, B
    real, dimension (:,:), allocatable :: C
    integer :: i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, l = 0
    integer :: m = 0, n = 0, p = 0, q = 0
    allocate(C(size(A,1)*size(B,1),size(A,2)*size(B,2)))
    C = 0
    do i = 1,size(A,1)
      do j = 1,size(A,2)
       n=(i-1)*size(B,1) + 1
       m=n+size(B,1) - 1
       p=(j-1)*size(B,2) + 1
       q=p+size(B,2) - 1
       C(n:m,p:q) = A(i,j)*B
      enddo
    enddo
  end function KronProd

end program myfun
```

**Edit:**  After editing the code using the comments below, the `z` vector gives the correct result.

I don't want a `do` loop every time I calculate the Kronecker product, so I'm trying the `KronProd` function from ECoulter's [`Kronecker.f95`](https://github.com/ECoulter/Kronecker/blob/master/Kronecker.f95).

In my code, `KronProd` is taken unchanged from `Kronecker.f95`. But I get `Error: Rank mismatch in argument 'a'  (rank-2 and rank-1)`. As pointed out by other users, there could be an issue with the `dimension (:,:), intent(in)`. How do I make this statement more general so that the `A` and `B` variables can take either matrices or arrays?

Comment: You've declared `z` as rank-1 (`z(:)`), but try to access it as rank-2 (`z(i,j)`). Which is right?

Comment: Either way, you don't allocate `z` at all, so it'll go wrong through that. Or declare `kronprod`.

Comment: `y = (/ 2,3,3 /) + (/ 1,2,-1 /) * complex(0,1)` is probably easier to understand as `y=[(2,1),(3,2),(3,-1)]`.

Comment: Also complex is not standard Fortran - `cmplx` is the appropriate function.

Comment: Having matched the shapes of `z` you still aren't allocating it.

Comment: @francescalus I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean by "allocating" or how to do this

Comment: `allocate(z(6))` somewhere near the start.  See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21046719/3157076) for ideas. That said, it's not at all obvious why you are using allocatable arrays given you are then assuming the sizes 2, 3 and 6.

Comment: @francescalus thanks it works with the `allocate(z(6))`. FWIW my code is structured like this because it's a MWE - my actual program uses much larger matrices and vectors

Comment: I added the necessary part of the code from the link. BUT please make sure this is really what you are actually compiling. You certainly cannot be compiling just the commented version you showed because A, B and C were not given a type and `implicit none` is present. a MRE should be minimal yes, but it should be **reproducible**. We have to be sure which code you are actually trying to compile.

Comment: If you are indeed using the linked version with `dimension (:,:), intent(in)` then I hope it is clear why `dimension(:)`, allocatable` is incompatible. If you use some version of your own that uses rank 1 arrays, the please show the exact complete code. If it is not clear, an answer can be written or linked.

Comment: Please also note that it is not clear if there is still some question to be answered or not and which exact question it would be. Please edit your question to some state that does not require reading all comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `KronProd` cannot be directly used because

1. It is intended for 2D (rank 2)arrays, not 1D (rank 1) arrays.
2. It is intended for real arrays, not complex ones.

There are multiple approaches how to enable the function.
First would be pointer remapping of the 1D arrays to a 2D arrays. The result would have to be remapped back. Because only one of.the arrays is complex, you could do the real part separately and the imaginary part separately. Or you can create a complex version of the subroutine.

Another approach would be creating multiple specific versions of the function (different array ranks and real/complex versions) and a generic interface.

For the remapping consider

```
real, dimension (:), allocatable, target :: x
complex, dimension (:), allocatable, target :: y
complex, dimension (:), allocatable, target :: z
real, pointer, dimension(:,:) :: xp
complex, pointer, dimension(:,:) :: yp, zp

...   

xp(1:size(x),1:1) => x
yp(1:size(y),1:1) => y
zp(1:size(z),1:1) => z

zp = KronProd_real_complex(xp,yp)
```

where the function is now

```
  function KronProd_real_complex(A,B) result(C)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    real, dimension (:,:), intent(in)  :: A
    complex, dimension (:,:), intent(in)  :: B
    complex, dimension (:,:), allocatable :: C
    integer :: i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, l = 0
    integer :: m = 0, n = 0, p = 0, q = 0
    allocate(C(size(A,1)*size(B,1),size(A,2)*size(B,2)))
    C = 0
    do i = 1,size(A,1)
      do j = 1,size(A,2)
       n=(i-1)*size(B,1) + 1
       m=n+size(B,1) - 1
       p=(j-1)*size(B,2) + 1
       q=p+size(B,2) - 1
       C(n:m,p:q) = A(i,j)*B
      enddo
    enddo
  end function KronProd_real_complex
```

Another option, and quite a good one for small arrays where performance is not an issue, is to just copy the 1D arrays into 2D arrays, separate the real and imaginary components in this way and call the original function.

```
  real, allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: x2d, y2d, z2d

  allocate(x2d(1:size(x),1))
  allocate(y2d(1:size(y),1))
  allocate(z2d(1:size(z),1))
  
  x2d(:,1) = x
  y2d(:,1) = y%re
  z2d = KronProd(x2d ,y2d)
  z%re = z2d(:,1)
  y2d(:,1) = y%im
  z2d = KronProd(x2d ,y2d)
  z%im = z2d(:,1)

  print *, z
```

This can also be hidden inside a function, potentially with automatic arrays instead of the allocatable ones.

Comment: As long as `y` is a rank-1 pointer/target, you shouldn't be worried about those pointer assignments.

Comment: @francescalus Thanks, I actually did the first revision when traveling home and then I forgot to check it and finish it. As I worried, Intel refuses the code because y%re is an expression which does not deliver a pointer result. I will come with a workaround. Gfortran compiles and runs the code but the results are wrong in a strange way - both the real and the imaginary part pointers being identical.

Comment: Ok, worrying that compilers don't behave properly is a valid worry. Silly Intel: `y%re` is an expression in the same way `y` is an expression. (They are, but they're both variables, and if `y` has the pointer or target attribute then `y%re` has, as it's a subobject of `y`.)